# MongoDB: '$redact' results to matching embedded objects only

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following style Collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5548d5ebb8157a53e9ceb9a4",
    "layers" : [
        { "_id" : "5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a0", "name" : "layer1"},
        { "_id" : "5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a1", "name" : "layer2"}
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "5548d5ebb8157a778899b9a5",
    "layers" : [
        { "_id" : "5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a2", "name" : "layer1"},
        { "_id" : "5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a3", "name" : "layer2"}
    ]
}
...
```

I now want to query for layers with certain `_id`. What I want is *only* an array of matching layer objects. Here is what I tried:

```
db.graphs.aggregate([
{ $match: { "layers._id": { $in: ["5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a1"] } } },
{ $redact : { $cond: 
    { if: 
        { $or : [
            { $eq: ["$_id","5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a1"] },
            { $not : "$_id" }]
        },
        then: "$$DESCEND",
        else: "$$PRUNE" 
    } 
} }]);
```

Doesn't work - I get an empty result. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution, short version:

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
    { $match: { "layers._id": { $in: ["5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a1"] } } }, 
    { $redact : { $cond:
        { if:
            { $or : [
                { $eq: ["$_id","5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a1"] },
                { $or : "$layers" }]
            },
            then: "$$DESCEND",
            else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
} }]);
```

Explanation: first understand that the `$redact` operator walks the matched documents level wise downwards, like a tree / graph. The problem here was that the top level document already contains an `_id` field. Therefore the `{ $not: "_id" }` expression evaluates to false. On the same, top level, so does the `{ $eq: ["$_id","5548c97eb8157a53e9ceb9a1"] }` expression since that id would only be found on the nested, next level. As a result the top level evaluates to false and "$$PRUNE" is done instead of "$$DESCEND".

The provided solution makes the top level pass by letting the test be true if the checked level has a `layers` property - which the top level, and only the top level, does have.